# Display JComboBox selection in JTable with a single click

Tags: jtable, jcombobox

**TL;DR** - JComboBox in JTable should displays its selection popup with a single click but it requires two clicks on occasion.  Why the inconsistent behavior?

**In Detail**

Code posted below is a simple one file full source code from Oracle so I suggest running the code sample and follow my test scenarios to see exactly what I'm talking about.

Running JComboBox in JTable example below, I noticed the inconsistent behavior of JComboBox displaying its selection popup.

***Test 1:***

Upon launching, click on "Knitting" under the "Sport" column.  You will notice that JComboBox will **display its selection popup instantly**.

Now, Click on Vegetarigan (Checkbox) column (any row is fine).  The checkbox will be checked on/off.

Go back and click on JComboBox again.  Once again, you will notice that it displays its popup instantly.

Consistent behavior so far.

***Test 2:***

Click on "Knitting" under the "Sport" column again. (if not already selected)

Only this time, instead of click on checkbox column, just Click on one row above, "Rowing", in the same Sport Column.  You will notice that it does not display its selection popup instantly.  You will have to **click it AGAIN (hence two clicks) to have its selection popup displayed.**

**Question:**

Has anybody noticed this inconsistent behavior and Is there anyway you can have JComboBox display its popup with single click all the time in JTable?

This inconsistent two click to display selections behavior seems to happen only between JComboBox Cells in JTable.  If you select any other components like TextField, JComboBox will display its selection instantly with one click

**TL;DR** - JComboBox in JTable should displays its selection popup with one click all the time but it requires two clicks on occasion.  Why the inconsistent behavior?

```
/*
 * TableRenderDemo.java requires no other files.
 */

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

/** 
 * TableRenderDemo is just like TableDemo, except that it
 * explicitly initializes column sizes and it uses a combo box
 * as an editor for the Sport column.
 */
public class TableRenderDemo extends JPanel {
    private boolean DEBUG = false;

    public TableRenderDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));

        JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        //Set up column sizes.
        initColumnSizes(table);

        //Fiddle with the Sport column's cell editors/renderers.
        setUpSportColumn(table, table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2));

        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    /*
     * This method picks good column sizes.
     * If all column heads are wider than the column's cells'
     * contents, then you can just use column.sizeWidthToFit().
     */
    private void initColumnSizes(JTable table) {
        MyTableModel model = (MyTableModel)table.getModel();
        TableColumn column = null;
        Component comp = null;
        int headerWidth = 0;
        int cellWidth = 0;
        Object[] longValues = model.longValues;
        TableCellRenderer headerRenderer =
            table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);

            comp = headerRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                                 null, column.getHeaderValue(),
                                 false, false, 0, 0);
            headerWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;

            comp = table.getDefaultRenderer(model.getColumnClass(i)).
                             getTableCellRendererComponent(
                                 table, longValues[i],
                                 false, false, 0, i);
            cellWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;

            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("Initializing width of column "
                                   + i + ". "
                                   + "headerWidth = " + headerWidth
                                   + "; cellWidth = " + cellWidth);
            }

            column.setPreferredWidth(Math.max(headerWidth, cellWidth));
        }
    }

    public void setUpSportColumn(JTable table,
                                 TableColumn sportColumn) {
        //Set up the editor for the sport cells.
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.addItem("Snowboarding");
        comboBox.addItem("Rowing");
        comboBox.addItem("Knitting");
        comboBox.addItem("Speed reading");
        comboBox.addItem("Pool");
        comboBox.addItem("None of the above");
        sportColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));

        //Set up tool tips for the sport cells.
        DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer =
                new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        renderer.setToolTipText("Click for combo box");
        sportColumn.setCellRenderer(renderer);
    }

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                                        "Last Name",
                                        "Sport",
                                        "# of Years",
                                        "Vegetarian"};
        private Object[][] data = {
        {"Kathy", "Smith",
         "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
        {"John", "Doe",
         "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Sue", "Black",
         "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
        {"Jane", "White",
         "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Joe", "Brown",
         "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
        };

        public final Object[] longValues = {"Jane", "Kathy",
                                            "None of the above",
                                            new Integer(20), Boolean.TRUE};

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        /*
         * JTable uses this method to determine the default renderer/
         * editor for each cell.  If we didn't implement this method,
         * then the last column would contain text ("true"/"false"),
         * rather than a check box.
         */
        public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
         * editable.
         */
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            //Note that the data/cell address is constant,
            //no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
            if (col < 2) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
         * data can change.
         */
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
                                   + " to " + value
                                   + " (an instance of "
                                   + value.getClass() + ")");
            }

            data[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);

            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("New value of data:");
                printDebugData();
            }
        }

        private void printDebugData() {
            int numRows = getRowCount();
            int numCols = getColumnCount();

            for (int i=0; i < numRows; i++) {
                System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
                for (int j=0; j < numCols; j++) {
                    System.out.print("  " + data[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableRenderDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        TableRenderDemo newContentPane = new TableRenderDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1995, 2008, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *   - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 *   - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 *   - Neither the name of Oracle or the names of its
 *     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *     from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
 * IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
 * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
 * PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */
```

Comment: Valid question, but far from [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Could you please condense your problem statement and code sample?

Comment: I attached the simple one file full source, so people can run it and see it for themselves as I described on the post.  This is indeed very odd behavior on JComboBox in JTable.  I am just baffled by its inconsistent behaviors.